# Filter variables by value in eclipse debug perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Hy,

Is there a way to filter the contents in the Variables view based on the value of variables.
Maybe a plugin or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of: **[bug 44701](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=44701)** (2003!) was *almost* there in 2006 with a patch...
But it is finally marked in 2009 as **`RESOLVED WONTFIX`**.